# IE not opening with protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

[attached screenshot, in config file 'browserName': 'internet explorer'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXRqX.png)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Ie driver executable path in the conf file as below:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe']
};
```

You can read about it [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/669#issuecomment-39467873)